# VC++ Process class change StreamReader behavior

Tags: .net, visual-c++

I have an application in VC++ that needs to read a text file on startup to set diverse value. I simply use a StreamReader object to read the file until the end and there is usually no problem here.

If I execute the application directly or debug it in visual studio, there won't be any problem and the text file will be read correctly.

The goal of this application is to be used as an extension of another main application. An extension is added and executed by giving the path of the application and a Process object is created. However, when the application is executed this way, the StreamReader does not read the text file correctly.

I am certain that my text file is in utf-8 but even if I create a StreamReader with utf-8 as encoding, it will read Français as Franǂais. In fact, any character other than letters and numbers will not be correct. I tried with a loop every possible encoding and none works.

There are other applications that are used as extension and those applications are opened the same way and they need to read a text file on start up too but there are no problem with those one.

I don't think it is an encoding problem since the application will read the text correctly if I launch it directly but it will fail if it is opened by the Process class.

Thanks for the help.